# Huge fibonacci modulo m C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to calculate Fn mod m, where Fn is the nth Fibonacci number. n may be really huge, so its really not efficient to calculate Fn in a straightforward way (matrix exponentiation **would** work, though). The problem statement asks us to do this *without* calculating Fn, using the distributive property of the modulo:
(a+b)mod m = [a mod m + b mod m] mod m

(Before anyone asks me, I looked up answers to this same problem. I'd like an answer to my specific question, however, since I'm not asking about the *algorithm* to solve this problem)

Using this and the fact that the nth Fibonacci number is just the sum of the previous two, I don't need to store Fibonacci numbers, but rather only the results of calculating successive modulo operations. In that sense, I should have an array F of size n which has in it stored the results of iteratively calculating Fn mod m using the above property. I have managed to solve this problem using the following code. However, upon reviewing it, I stumbled upon something that rather confused me.

```
long long get_fibonacci_huge_mod(long long n, long long m) {

    long long Fib[3] = {0, 1, 1};
    long long result;
    long long index;
    long long period;
    long long F[n+1];
    F[0] = 0;
    F[1] = 1;
    F[2] = 1;

    for (long long i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
      F[i] = (F[i-2] + F[i-1]) % m;
      if (F[i] == 0 && F[i+1] == 1 && F[i+2] == 1) {
        period = i;
        break;
      }
    }


    index = n % period;
    result = F[index];
    return result;

}
```

This solution outputs correct results for any n and m, even if they are quite large. It might get a little bit slow when n is huge, but I'm not worried about that right now. I'm interested in specifically solving the problem this way. I'll try solving it using matrix exponentiation or any other much faster algorithm *later*.

So my question is as follows. At the beginning of the code, I create an array F of size n+1. Then I iterate through this array calculating Fn mod m using the distributive property. One thing that confused me after writing this loop was the fact that, since F was initialized to all zeros, *how is it correctly using F[i+2], F[i+1], if they haven't been calculated yet?* I assume that they are being correctly used since the algorithm outputs **correct** results every time. Perhaps this assumption is wrong?

My question isn't about the algorithm per se, I'm asking about what's going on *inside* the loop.

Thank you

Comment: It is not correct to use `F[i+1]` or `F[i+2]`, and will lead to undefined behavior when `i >= n-1`.

Comment: A couple of things: The code you show is not valid C++ code since it's using [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (some compilers allow it as an extension though). Then the contents of `F` is *not* initialized to zero, only `F[0]` is (after the definition of `F`).

Comment: Can you add which inputs you have tested and the corresponding results?

Comment: Using n=239 and m=1000, output should be 161
Using n=2816213588 and m=30524 output should be 10249 (this one takes a bit)
Using n=1 m=239 output should be 1

Comment: Hmm... If it isn't correct to use them, how should I attempt a similar thing? And why is it working?

Comment: "F was initialized to all zeros" - no it wasn't. It wasn't initialised at all, and using the values in `F[i+1]` and `F[i+2]` is undefined.

Comment: I printed out F[0] through F[n] for a small n and got all zeros, though. What's going on here? I compiled my code using g++ -pipe -O2 -std=c++14 fibonacci_huge.cpp -lm

Comment: @EmilioBotero Zero is one example of an indeterminate value which is invalid to use for anything. You can't determine whether an object has been initialised by inspecting it. You also can't assume that a program is correct just because it produces the correct output. Welcome to C++.

Comment: Why does this prohram need an array? If I ask you to find the tenth Fibonacci number using a piece of paper, what would you do?

Comment: If your numbers are not growing to large, consider computing the n-th number by formula instead of iterating the whole fibonacci sequence. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html ... well maybe not really suited here, because the requirement seems to enforce intermediate modulo to let the result even fit into the number space

Comment: @n.m., typically I'd just sum the previous two numbers. If I need the 100000th Fibonacci number, however, and need to calculate the remainder when dividing it by some number m, I figure I don't need to calculate Fibonacci numbers at all, only their remainders. This stops any integer overflow issues

Comment: Ok so where did an array enter the picture and why?

Comment: Because to output the final result, i.e Fn mod m, I need F[index], where index = n mod period. The loop is supposed to find the Pisano period that results when you calculate the remainder of dividing successive Fibonacci numbers by m. Since the array F starts with [0,1,1], I thought I'd just look for the next time this happened to find the period.

Comment: First of all, the lines: period = i; break;
are never being hit. Second, the reason its working is because your period variable is being initialized to CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC, which is an implementation detail, so index = n % period is simply giving you n, which it will do unless n exceeds CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC.

Comment: OK so you want to find the period then look at already calculated numbers to output the final result. Fair enough, but who told you you will find the period? Perhaps it's larger than n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a faulty implementation of a correct algorithm. Let us look at the corrected version first.

```
long long get_fibonacci_huge_mod(long long n, long long m) {
    long long result;
    long long index;
    long long period = n+1;
    long long sz = min (n+1,m*m+1); // Bound for period
    long long *F = new long long[sz];
    F[0] = 0;
    F[1] = 1;
    F[2] = 1;

    for (long long i = 3; i < sz; i++) {
      F[i] = (F[i-2] + F[i-1]) % m;
      if (F[i] == 1 && F[i-1] == 0) { // we have got back to where we started
        period = i-1;
        break;
      }
    }

    index = n % period;
    result = F[index];
    delete[]F;
    return result;

}
```

So why does the original code work? Because you got lucky. The checks for i+1 and i+2 never evaluated to true because of the lucky garbage the array was initialized to. As a result this reduced to the naive evaluation of F(n) without incorporating periodicity at all.

Comment: Uninitialized `period` when the actual period is larger than `n`.

Comment: Thanks, initialised to n+1.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the answer. However, using n=2816213588 and m=30524 outputs 17721, whereas answer should be 10249.

Comment: Had made an off-by-one error, should now give correct answer.

Comment: Works perfectly now. Could you explain what you are doing by calculating sz and using pointers?

Comment: Just what is mentioned in the code. m*m gives an upper bound for the periodicity - so if it is less than n, you only need an array of so many elements. Since you are making an array with size not known at compile time, it is better to allocate memory with pointers through new[] and delete[].

Comment: So my mistakes were in how I created the array and also how I looked for the periodicity. When I wrote the loop and then saw I was accessing elements I had not calculated yet, I wondered whether I had broken c++ or something. Dumb mistakes, but left me really confused as to why it was working.